# Prove that if a function $f: X\to Y$ continuous then its graph is closed

Tags: metric-spaces

The graph of $f$ is $G(f) = \{(x,f(x)) : x\in X\} \subseteq X\times Y$

$X$ and $Y$ are metric spaces.

a) Suppose $f$ is continuous and prove that $G(f)$ is a closed set.

b) Suppose that $G(f)$ is compact and prove that $f$ is continous

For a), the definition of a closed set that comes to my mind is a set that contains all its limit points (or was it accumulation points?), is there another equivalent definition that may b more helpful to prove a)? Is it possible to prove this directly? Because at first glance the only way I could imagine to prove this is by contradiction or contrapositive.

I imagine that the proof of b) will be immediately derived from a).

Comment: You tagged your question as "real-analysis". What are $X$ and $Y$? Are they any topological spaces?

Comment: they are metric spaces. Thanks for pointing that out. @girianshiido

Comment: For metric spaces, you can use the convenient characterisation of closed sets. A set is closed off it is sequentially closed, i.e. iff it contains the limits of every convergent sequences with terms in $S$. It's also easy to prove the continuity of $f$ using sequences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a) Let $(z_n)=(x_n,f(x_n))$ be a convergent sequence of $G(f)$. If $(x,y)$ is its limit, show that $y=f(x)$.

b) Let $x\in X$ and $(x_n)$ a convergent sequence with limit $x$. You have to prove that $(f(x_n))$ is convergent in $Y$ with limit $f(x)$. Use the sequence $z_n=(x_n,f(x_n))$ and use the fact that $G(f)$ is compact to prove that $(f(x_n))$ has $f(x)$ as an accumulation point. 
Then prove that any subsequence of $(f(x_n))$ has $f(x)$ as an accumulation point.

Comment: Can you expand on part a, please. How does showing that y = f(x) complete the proof?

Comment: It proves that $(x,y)=(x,f(x))\in G(f)$. So every convergent sequence $(z_n)\in G(f)^{\mathbb N}$ has its limit in $G(f)$. Hence $G(f)$ is closed.

Comment: Ok I see. Could you sketch the proof that the limit $(x,y) = (x,f(x))$?

Comment: If $(z_n)$ is convergent with limit $(x,y)$, then $(x_n)$ and $f(x_n)$ are both convergent with limits $x$ and $y$ respectively. Since $f$ is continuous, $y=\lim f(x_n)=f(x)$.

Comment: One small thing, how do we know that there exists a convergent sequence in $G(f)$? Is it just a given?

Comment: A subset $C$ of a metric space $X$ is closed iff all convergent sequences with terms in $C$ have their limits in $C$. So it's a given.

Comment: In part b, how does the compactness of $G(f)$ imply that $f(x)$ has is an accumulation point of $f(x_n)$?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11111/discussion-between-girianshiido-and-johanliebert)

Comment: I have a question for part b). There is subsequence $(x_{n_k},f(x_{n_k})) \to (x,y)\in G_f$. Then we will have $y=f(x)$ but how do I prove that $f(x_n) \to f(x)$? It is true that every subsequence of $f(x_n)$ has a subsequence converging to $f(x)$. Can you please elaborate that part? I have also posted the question here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3967999/f-is-continuous-iff-gf-is-a-closed-set-in-metric-spaces

Answer (score 3):

Hint: For (a), every metric space is Hausdorff, the result is frue for any Hausdorff space $Y$. Choose any (x,y)\in $X\times Y\setminus G(f)$. Then $x\in X$ and $y\ne f(x)$. Use Hausdorff condition in $Y$.

Comment: I have no idea what a Hausdorff space is. We haven't covered that yet in the course. Is there another way?

Comment: @ Johan Liebert: Yes, see how girianshiido does.

Answer (score 2):

We want to show that every sequence which converges in $X\times Y$ has a limit in $G(f)$.

A sequence $(x_n, y_n)$ converges to $(x, y)$ if and only if $x_n\rightarrow x$ and $y_n\rightarrow y$.

Note that $(x_n, y_n)\in N_\epsilon(x, y)\implies(x_n)\in N_\epsilon(x) $ and $(y_n)\in  N_\epsilon(y)$ respectively.

Conversely, if $x_n \in N_{\epsilon/2}(x)$ and $y_n \in N_{\epsilon/2}(y)$, then $(x_n, y_n)\in N_\epsilon(x, y)$.

So now we see that if $(x_n, y_n)\in G(f)$, $(x_n,y_n) \rightarrow (x,y)$, then $y_n\rightarrow f(x_n)$ as defined by $G(f)$ and $x_n \rightarrow x, f(x_n)\rightarrow y.$

Since $f$ is assumed to be continuous, $f(x_n)\rightarrow f(x)$ so $y=f(x)$. Therefore $(x,y)\in G(f)$ and we conclude $G(f)$ is closed.